# jquery/ajax populate second dropdown and trigger change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So I managed to populate 3 cascading dropdownboxes.
The issue though is when one dropdown is populated: it's first option isn't fired as a changed event.

Here is an example of 2 changes:

```
$('#timesheet-type').change(function () {
    var clients = $('#timesheet-client');
    var projects = $('#timesheet-project');
    if ($(this).val() == 'project') {
        $.getJSON("timesheets/populateClients",
            function (data) {
                var model = clients;
                model.empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                    model.append("<option value='" + element.id + "'>" + element.first_name + "</option>");
                });
            });
        clients.prop('disabled', false);
        clients.change();
    } else {
        clients.prop('disabled', true);
        projects.prop('disabled', true);
    }
});

$('#timesheet-client').change(function () {
    $('#timesheet-project').prop('disabled', false);
    $.getJSON("timesheets/populateProjects",
        { option: $(this).val() },
        function (data) {
            var model = $('#timesheet-project');
            model.empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                model.append("<option value='" + element.id + "'>" + element.name + "</option>");
            });
        });
});
```

So to fire the next dropdown using the first option I need to switch twice.

using:

```
clients.change()
/* or */
clients.trigger('change');
```

enables the combobox, but doesnt populate.

Comment: do you mind if there's no ajax used?

Comment: Perhaps you could add an _empty_ option as the very first item in each list? Then selecting the next item (the first 'real' option) would be easy :)

Comment: @ejay_francisco: unfortunatly no other way.

Comment: @Doku-so: I thought of this but the fact is I like to navigate with as less clicks as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10547666

Below is a modified code for your situation:

First set the val() and then trigger() the event to manually fire it
[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/v7QWd/3/) ( http://jsfiddle.net/v7QWd/3/ )

```
$('#timesheet-type')
         .val('YOUR-OPTION-VALUE-HERE')
         .trigger('change');
```

You could still have an empty option (if necessary) on top of each list, and from your JavaScript code automatically set the value (selected item) to the actual option.

Comment: thanks this worked for me. I was sending the event first then the val. Was stuck on it until I came across this post