# AngularJS trigger for select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I use `trigger('click')` for radio buttons and select box. It works for radio button right :

```
angular.forEach(angular.element.find('input'), function(node){
    angular.forEach(result.data.test, function(value, key){
        if(node.value == value.FieldValue) {

            // ** JUST SEE THIS LINE ** //
            // This works fine in radio button
            angular.element("#" + node.id).trigger('click');

        }
    });
});
```

See line **.

**But it doesn't work for select box :**

```
angular.forEach(angular.element.find('select, option'), function(node){

    angular.forEach(result.data.test, function(value, key){
        if(node.value == value.FieldValue) {

            // This line doesn't work!!! //
            angular.element("#" + node.id).trigger('click');

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger change event <select> using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547622/trigger-change-event-select-using-jquery)

Comment: @Dhaval It doesn't work in AngularJS. When I use `angular.element("#" + node.id).value.trigger('click');` , It gives me this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined`

Comment: Can you please provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

why trigger is not working with select element is because select element selection is decided by value.
you can set each options value as node.id
and in your forEach loop you can set value to node.id insted of triggering click.

```
angular.forEach(angular.element.find('select, option'), function(node){
    angular.forEach(result.data.test, function(value, key){
        if(node.value == value.FieldValue) {
            angular.element.find('select').val(node.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It gives me this error: `TypeError: angular.element.find(...).val is not a function`

Comment: @user3532446 seems like your done don't have any select element.