# Atleast one drop down value must be selected from multiple drop downs using jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I have multiple drop downs in a table and at least one drop-down from table  should be selected as per the business rule. I am using jquery validation plugin and jsf.
  Thanks in advance!!
// jsf code

```
div id="hoursShiftsModal">
   <table id="hoursShiftsTable">
          <col width="5%"/>
          <col width="5%"/>
           <col width="5%"/>
           <col width="5%"/>
        <thead>
        <tr>
              <th>Hours</th>
             <th>Jan</th>
             <th>Feb</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td><label>Starting</label></td>
    <td>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="janStartTime" class="required timeZone      workShiftsGroup" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Select" itemLabel="Select" ></f:selectItem> 
    <f:selectItems value=" "></f:selectItems>                                                                                                                                                               
   </h:selectOneMenu>
   </td>
  <td>
   <h:selectOneMenu id="febStartTime" class="required timeZone workShiftsGroup "  >
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Select" itemLabel="Select" ></f:selectItem> 
   <f:selectItems ></f:selectItems>                                                                                                                                                               
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 </td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIps5.jpg)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might work: it will search for 'selected' options nested in your tables.

```
function valid() {
    return $('#hoursShiftsTable select option[selected=selected][value!=" "]').size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi efilho " $('#hoursShiftsTable select option[selected=selected][value!=" "]') " it didn't give me any selected options.

Comment: Oh you want the SELECTED OPTIONS values??? I thought you wanted a validation if there were any selected option, sorry. In this case: `$('#hoursShiftsTable select option[selected=selected][value!=" "]').each(function(i,j){alert(j.value);})` this will iterate over the selected values (represented by `j.value`)

Comment: If you see my above code my first option in drop down is "select" . For my validations I want to change drop down option from select to empty value. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547622/trigger-change-event-select-using-jquery, I tried and it worked. In your case: `$('#hoursShiftsTable select').val(' ').trigger('change');`. Hope it helps, best regards.

Comment: Will this give me value of column of next row !!$("#" + elemId  + 'td:nth-child(1) option:selected' ).text()