# How to trigger a event on a select element to select first option with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-listener

I have several dropdown elements of countries that have onchange listeners attached to them that change the list of states in an additional dropdown list based on the country selected.

I want to have the country preselected based on the user's region, but I figure the best way to do this is to just trigger a onchange event on load and set it to the country.

I figured out I can create an event and dispatch it to my country dropdowns, which is great:

```
var event; // The custom event that will be created
if (document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent('onchange');
    event.eventName = "onchange";
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

But this is just triggering the change on another. I want it to trigger the change to select the first option in the country dropdown element. How do I write it to select the first option?

Comment: @Nit, please reconsider opening my question. I changed it to add more clarity.

Comment: @TheCrazyProgrammer , please reconsider opening my question. I changed it to add more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found the correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126498/10537235). My code is, as follows

```
var sortBySelect: NodeListOf<HTMLSelectElement> | null = document.querySelectorAll("select.Country-List");
if (sortBySelect != null) {
    sortBySelect.forEach((select) => {
        select.value = "USA";
        select.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
    });
}
```

I query for all the select elements that are country drop downs, set them to the value for United States, and the dispatch a simple change event. This way, my listeners for the states element triggers and populates, saving me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, I don't know if that's what you mean?!

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.onchange = function() {
  console.log("changed");
}
window.onload = function() {
  input.onchange();
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: thanks, but not quite. I change the question to reflect what I am looking form